# How to respond to internal move in QT's listview of a QStringListModel

Tags: c++, qt

My app is almost done. I'm stuck trying to update elements of my mainwindow when I move an item up or down in a simple listview model that has a QStringListModel as its backend.

Here is my model for allowing drag/drop:

```
#ifndef MYMODEL_H
#define MYMODEL_H

#include <QStringListModel>

class mymodel : public QStringListModel
{
public:
    mymodel(QObject * parent = nullptr);
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;
};
#endif // MYMODEL_H
```

The model implementation is:

```
#include "mymodel.h"

mymodel::mymodel(QObject *parent) : QStringListModel (parent) {}

Qt::ItemFlags mymodel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags defaultFlags = QStringListModel::flags(index);

    if (index.isValid())
    {
        return  Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled |
                Qt::ItemIsEnabled ;
    }
    else
    {
        return  Qt::ItemIsSelectable  | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled |
                Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags;
    }
}
```

Here is my implementation, which does work, except I cannot detect if I move a row up down.

```
    //create model
    model = new mymodel(this);

    //make some data
    QStringList List;
    List << "one" << "two" << "three";

   // populate the model
    model->setStringList(List);

    // create a list view
     QListView *lv = new QListView(this);

    // glue model and view together
    lv->setModel(model);

    // allow modifying the data in Listview
    lv->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
    lv->setDragDropOverwriteMode(false);
    lv->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::AnyKeyPressed |
                        QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked);
```

I've tried all of the following, they do compile, but don't do anything.

They are supposed to simply console print 'something happened', but they don't.

```
    // doesnt do anything! compiles
    connect(lv, &QListView::indexesMoved,
            this, &MainWindow::rowsMoved);

    // doesnt do anything! compiles
    connect(lv->model(), &QStringListModel::rowsMoved,
            this, &MainWindow::rowsMoved);

    // doesnt do anything! compiles
    connect(lv->model(), &QAbstractItemModel::rowsMoved,
            this, &MainWindow::rowsMoved);
```

The rowsMoved is declared in the headers with:

```
void rowsMoved(const QModelIndex &parent, int start, int end, const QModelIndex &destination, int row);
};
```

In the interim, I have found that adding to constructor:

```
lv->installEventFilter(this);
```

In the cpp as well as later defined as:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (object == lv)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::ChildRemoved) {
            qDebug() << "drop event!";

        // iterate over the listview and print out it's data,
        // so if you wanted this back in your stringlist.. this is
        // where you'd do it:
        for (int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); ++i)
        {
            qDebug().noquote() <<  model->index(i, 0).data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
        }
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This gets me a 'poor mans notification' but it feels 'dirty'

Comment: A question: Why do you want to detect if the displacement is from top to bottom or vice versa?

Comment: The data source seems to never be updated.  In my case I'm using a String List.  So when I make changes in the list view, something as simple as moving an item up or down, that change is never propogated to the data set.  So I'm left in an inconsistent state.  So I'm looking to find when the list views data is changed, or moved about and write that back to a new list.

Comment: QStringListModel is a model that does not allow the modification of internal data, why don't you use QStandardItemModel?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean my modify internal data: I'm already deleting rows, inserting rows, drag items from file manager onto my list, etc.  I'm simply looking for a way to hook into some signal that must be emmited when the user modifies data.

Comment: Using an eventFilter does not make sense since the QEvent::ChildRemoved event is only sent when a QObject child of a QObject is removed and the items of a model are not QObject so that event will not be emitted.

Comment: A QStringListModel only allows you to set a QStringList (a reset) and there is no other possible modification. QStringListModel is made to display a non-modifiable list so the drag-and-drop does not work on that model. Solution: Use an editable model such as the QStandardItemModel.

Comment: Correct at this time, the event filter only gets triggered if I do an 'internal' move of an item up/down the list.  If I 'delete' a row, then the filter does not get triggered.

Comment: The filter must not be activated by moving an item, modifying or deleting an item since the items are not QObject. QEvent::ChildRemoved only fires if a child QObject is removed from a parent but I emphasize: the items of model are not QObject

Comment: So any idea's on what I need to do?  I'm not looking to keep the filter.

Comment: You can explain your phrase: *So when I make changes in the list view, something as simple as moving an item up or down, that change is never propogated to the data set*. How do you verify that the data has not changed?

Comment: I had set a break point after a drop event took place, and looked at the String list that held the data that I used with setStringList

Comment: mmm, The QStringListModel **copies the QStringList** passed to the model through the setStringList method, so any modification of the model will not be applied to the original QStringList but to the internal copy.

Comment: exactly, ugh.  So I'm open to suggestions, I can change the app to use a diff model if need be.  The doc's had led me down this path as the way I interpreted them.  But I'm not looking to go all *hardcore* and use QAsbstract Model and rewrite QT lol

Comment: If you want to recover the modified QStringList you must use the [stringList()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html#stringList) method: `QStringList new_list = your_model->stringList();`

Comment: I suppose I could place a button next to my list view "Save Changes" and it invoke that.  Gonna have to find some signal tho that says something changed in the list view to make end user aware they should click the button.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean about QStandardItem Model, this does yield an event changed signal:

Comment: I will have to do more testing on delete, drag/drop etc wish me luck

Comment: I don't see how to give eyllanesc credit for the advise, if  someone could  guide me how to do that I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

So grateful that eyllanesc helped me!  Thank you.

Posting this here, should any one need.

This code indeed does allow me edit items, move them up/down in the list view, and be notified when something in the list is changed by the user.  In addition, not shown  below, the below allows drag / drop
operations from file manager  which for my app I need.

If you were to compare my original post based on QStringListModel you'll notice they look almost exactly the same.  I am still perplexed why using that model did not work.  But facts are facts, this works and the other does not.

mymodel.h

```
#ifndef MYMODEL_H
#define MYMODEL_H

#include <QStandardItemModel>
class mymodel : public QStandardItemModel
{

public:
    mymodel(QObject * parent = nullptr);
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;
};

#endif // MYMODEL_H
```

mymodel.cpp

```
#include "mymodel.h"
#include <QDebug>

mymodel::mymodel(QObject *parent) : QStandardItemModel (parent) {}

Qt::ItemFlags mymodel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags defaultFlags = QStandardItemModel::flags(index);

    if (index.isValid())
    {
        return  Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled |
                Qt::ItemIsEnabled    | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    }
    else
    {
        return  Qt::ItemIsSelectable  | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled |
                Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags;
    }
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QListView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStringList>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    QListView *lv;
    QStringList list;
    QStandardItemModel *model;

private slots:
    void itemChanged();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QDebug>
#include "mymodel.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
    lv = new QListView(this);
    model = new mymodel(lv);

    list << "one" << "two" << "three";
    for (int i=0; i < list.length(); ++i)
    {
        model->appendRow(new QStandardItem(list[i]));
    }

    lv->setModel(model);
    lv->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
    lv->setDragDropOverwriteMode(false);
    QBoxLayout *lo = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::LeftToRight);
    lo->addWidget(lv);
    setLayout(lo);

    connect(model, &QStandardItemModel::itemChanged,
            this,  &MainWindow::itemChanged);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::itemChanged()
{
    qDebug().noquote() << "an item changed";
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QListView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStringList>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    QListView *lv;
    QStringList list;
    QStandardItemModel *model;

private slots:
    void itemChanged();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: no this doesn't work either... when draggin internal items it leaves duplicates.

Comment: Update, it does work, the data changed event is firing before removeRows and hence I see a ghost/doube but debugger shows it is deleted.